# hotw to do a code morse code using Trie with Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, trie, morse-code

I need to make a program that translates / inserts / removes morse code using tries, I got a part however in the search (buscar), when I just put a part of the morse code it returns the letter that starts with that dot or dash, which I don't want. To'A', for example the user needs to type '.-' and not only '.'. I also have no idea how to remove the elements that the user want. help me

ps: some words are in portuguese

my code:

```
class TrieNode:
"""A node in the trie structure"""

def __init__(self, char):
    # the character stored in this node
    self.char = char

    # whether this can be the end of a word
    self.is_end = False

    # a counter indicating how many times a word is inserted
    # (if this node's is_end is True)
    self.counter = 0

    # a dictionary of child nodes
    # keys are characters, values are nodes - keys are point and trace, values are caracteres
    self.children = {}

class Trie(object):
"""The trie object"""

def __init__(self):
    """
    The trie has at least the root node.
    The root node does not store any character
    """
    self.root = TrieNode("")

def insert(self, word):
    """Insert a word into the trie"""
    node = self.root
    cont = 0
    
    # Loop through each character in the word
    # Check if there is no child containing the character, create a new child for the current node
    for char in word:
        if char in node.children:
            node = node.children[char]
        else:
            # If a character is not found,
            # create a new node in the trie
            new_node = TrieNode(char)
            node.children[char] = new_node
            node = new_node
            cont +=1
    if cont == 0:
        return 'Codigo ja utilizado'
    
    # Mark the end of a word
    node.is_end = True
    return 'Caractere inserido com sucesso'

    # Increment the counter to indicate that we see this word once more
    
def dfs(self, node, prefix):
    """Depth-first traversal of the trie
    
    Args:
        - node: the node to start with
        - prefix: the current prefix, for tracing a
            word while traversing the trie
    """
    if node.is_end:
        self.output.append(node.char)
        
    
    for child in node.children.values():
        self.dfs(child, prefix + node.char)
    
def query(self, x):
    """Given an input (a prefix), retrieve all words stored in
    the trie with that prefix, sort the words by the number of 
    times they have been inserted
    """
    # Use a variable within the class to keep all possible outputs
    # As there can be more than one word with such prefix
    self.output = []
    node = self.root
    
    # Check if the prefix is in the trie
    for char in x:
        if char in node.children:

            node = node.children[char]
        else:
            return False
    
    # Traverse the trie to get all candidates
    self.dfs(node, x[:-1])

    # Sort the results in reverse order and return
    return sorted(self.output)

def remove(self, node):
    print('idk')




tree = Trie()
invalido = False
while True:
    escolha = input()
    escolha_separar = escolha.split()
    if escolha_separar[0] == 'INSERIR:':
        print(tree.insert(escolha_separar[2] + escolha_separar[1]))
    if escolha_separar[0] == "BUSCAR:":
        try:
            resultado = tree.query(escolha_separar[1])
            print(resultado[-1])
        except:
            print('Codigo Invalido')
    if escolha_separar[0] == "REMOVER:":
        tree.query(escolha_separar[1])
    
    if escolha_separar[0] == 'DECODIFICAR:':
        r = ''
        tamanho = len(escolha_separar) - 1
        for codigo in range(tamanho):
            resultado1 = tree.query(escolha_separar[codigo+1])
            if resultado1 == False:
                invalido = True
                break
            else:
                r += resultado1[-1]
        if not invalido:
            print(r)
        else:
            print(f'Codigo Invalido: {escolha_separar[codigo+1]}')
            
        
    if escolha_separar[0] == 'FIM':
        break
```

Comment: If your dfs searches for a prefix, wouldn't "." match with ".-"?

Comment: What have you find out while debugging a minimal failing example?